# How to implement Save As Draft functionality in liferay 7

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7, liferay-6.2

I have a one HTML JSP form with accordion. I w want to implement a "Save as draft" feature in that form. Can any body help me?

Comment: Are you using [Service Builder](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/service-builder)?

Comment: yes i am using service builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks I got the solution for this and thanks to you for response.

for this we have to set the status flag in the database. and liferay give the by default this method WorkflowConstant.STATUS_DRAFT by default it will take 2 check your status value if it is same then it will store in db as draft otherwise submitted.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX1s9.png)

Answer (score 0):

"Save as draft" simply means the workflow status is assigned the value of DRAFT. Portlets like WebContentDisplay know to only show journal articles that have APPROVED (published) status.

Correspondingly when you go to edit the article, it will pull the DRAFT version instead of starting a new edit.

So there is nothing magical here, it is just regular code to do the appropriate thing based upon the status of the entity.